# O que são colunas-lista de uma data.frame?

Tags: r, lista, data.frame, tidyverse

O [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) estimula o uso de colunas-lista em [data.frames](/questions/tagged/data.frames). Mas, afinal,

- o que são colunas-lista?
- em que ocasiões elas são comumente usadas?
- elas podem ser criadas com o `r-base` ou apenas como `tibble`s?

Por exemplo,

```
data.frame(idade = 1:5, nome = letters[1:5], lista = lapply(1:5, rnorm))
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
>
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

```
tibble::tibble(idade = 1:5, nome = letters[1:5], lista = lapply(1:5, rnorm))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  idade nome  lista    
  <int> <chr> <list>   

1     1 a     <dbl [1]>
2     2 b     <dbl [2]>
3     3 c     <dbl [3]>
4     4 d     <dbl [4]>
5     5 e     <dbl [5]>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colunas-lista ou *list-columns* são uma estrutura de dados que podem ser úteis em diversos momentos quando trabalhando com o tidyverse. Elas são usadas principalmente como estruturas intermediárias.

Elas podem ser usadas no R-base mas você terá que usar a função `I` para prevenir que o base solte um erro. Exemplo:

```
data.frame(idade = 1:5, nome = letters[1:5], lista = I(lapply(1:5, rnorm)))

  idade nome        lista
1     1    a 0.178046....
2     2    b 0.407768....
3     3    c -0.84749....
4     4    d -0.44864....
5     5    e 1.229863....
```

Um exemplo que ilustra bem o uso de colunas-lista é quando estamos usando funções vetorizadas que retornam mais de um valor dentro de um mutate. Por exemplo:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~x1,
  "a,b,c", 
  "d,e,f,g"
) 

df %>% 
  mutate(x2 = stringr::str_split(x1, ","))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x1      x2       
#>   <chr>   <list>   
#> 1 a,b,c   <chr [3]>
#> 2 d,e,f,g <chr [4]>
```

Em seguida, é comum simplificar o data.frame usando a função `unnest` do `tidyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x2 = stringr::str_split(x1, ",")) %>% 
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   x1      x2   
#>   <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 a,b,c   a    
#> 2 a,b,c   b    
#> 3 a,b,c   c    
#> 4 d,e,f,g d    
#> 5 d,e,f,g e    
#> 6 d,e,f,g f    
#> # ... with 1 more row
```

Tem muitos outros casos de uso interessantes. Um outro exemplo que gosto bastante é o criado pelo pacote `rsample`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

vfold_cv(mtcars, v = 5) %>% 
  mutate(
    modelos = map(splits, ~lm(mpg ~ ., data = analysis(.x))),
    mse = map2_dbl(modelos, splits, ~mean((assessment(.y)$mpg - predict(.x, assessment(.y)))^2))
    )

#  5-fold cross-validation 
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  splits         id    modelos    mse
* <list>         <chr> <list>   <dbl>
1 <split [25/7]> Fold1 <S3: lm> 40.4 
2 <split [25/7]> Fold2 <S3: lm>  5.99
3 <split [26/6]> Fold3 <S3: lm>  9.11
4 <split [26/6]> Fold4 <S3: lm> 11.6 
5 <split [26/6]> Fold5 <S3: lm> 21.3
```

No exemplo acima ajustamos um modelo para cada fold da validação cruzada e em seguida calculamos o erro quadrático médio para as observações que ficam de fora em cada fold.